# Как создать 64 битныю версию приложения для Android

Tags: android

Согласно новым правилам Гуугл "В 2019 году новые приложения и обновления с нативными библиотеками должны будут содержать 64-разрядные версии". Для этого достаточно компилировать приложение через 64-битную версию Android Studio и всё???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Это касается только приложений с нативными модулями или библиотеками.
Если в вашем APK нет ни одного `*.so` файла (только dex-код), ничего делать вообще не надо.

Разрядность Android Studio тут вообще не при делах.

Первоисточник:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html

> In August 2019, Play will require that new apps and app updates with native libraries provide 64-bit versions in addition to their 32-bit versions.
>
> Apps that do not include native code are unaffected.